# Why should we avoid using class variables @@ in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Why should we avoid using class variables @@ in rails? Is there any security loopholes with that. Please answer as I am new with rails. and I am much using instance variable `@variable_name` . I tried once `@@variable_name` .

I know only about class variable is, *Class variable is sharable between object*

But I really would like to know  **Why should we avoid using class variables @@ in rails?**

Comment: That sounds like `static` variables in Java. No reason not to use it, just be aware that it doesn't belong to your instance and could change asynchronously.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Simply because they are not thread safe. Many rails=capable servers are multi-threaded. That means there may be multiple running instances of your application at any given time and any request by one of your users is going to be arbitrarily assigned to one of them. Class variables are not shared between processes so there is a possibility that your class variable will be different in a subsequent request.

Even if you deliberately manage to run your app in a single threaded server, there is no guarantee that your app won't be restarted between requests, losing your class variable.

If you want functionality similar to what class variables provide, I strongly recommend that you look into key-value stores such as Memcached or Redis.

Comment: Nothing is shared between processes, not just @@vars. Guess we shouldn't use @vars also for the same reason, should we?

Comment: @Victor Well, `@variables` are instance variables and they are consistent **within** a request because a request spawns a new instance of a controller. Just don't expect to find them in the next request.

Comment: @edgerunner `@@vars` are not about sharing between requests, but about sharing between instances of the same class (and subclasses in this particularly case which makes them a bit dangerous unless you know what you are doing). Check e.g. ActiveRecord, ActiveSupport -- `@@vars` are still there as of 3.1.3

Comment: @VictorMoroz in rails, thread consistency isn't guaranteed in rails. Therefore it is risky to use class variables if you expect them to persist across requests. Of course there are some edge cases where using a class variable may be a good idea but for 99% of rails use cases, it is a bad idea.

Comment: @edgerunner I didn't realize somebody would use `@@vars` for saving state (OP didn't indicate that). Guess besides Memcached or Redis we usually use session in Rails for that purpose. At the same time when properly initialized `@@vars` (as well as class-level `@vars`) are quite safe both in production and development mode, e.g. for storing  values persistent in this particular rails process.

Comment: @VictorMoroz, OP has indicated that she is new in rails. I doubt that she would use rails beyond the basics yet. Class variables can be useful when writing engines and plugins, but they are somewhere between useless and dangerous when used in the typical model or controller classes. `session` is good as you said in some persistence cases, but `session` is, as its name says, a specific user's session and it is not shared between users.

Comment: @edgerunner "Class variables can be useful when writing engines and plugins" can you provide examples or links to details of this please? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaeldeSilva Simple example right here: You could use a class variable to store the value of an API token that you would request from an external service during startup. Then that API token is available to the class all through the run time and it can be updated when it times out. It is independent of any user's session or any single request.