# Instance variable in model can not be accessed from within method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails app, and I've run into a small issue, but I can't seem to find any information pertaining to my certain case.

I'm getting an `undefined method error '[]' for NilClass` when calling the `add_user` method in an instance of the class below.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  @user_info = Hash.new

  def add_user(user_id)
    new_info = OpenStruct.new
    new_info.score1 = 0
    new_info.score2 = 0
    @user_info[user_id] = new_info
  end

  ...

end
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? In a C++, Java program the equivalent would work fine but I guess Ruby works a bit differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instance Variables in Rails Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252940/instance-variables-in-rails-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your class is a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`, you probably should not override the constructor. You can do the initialization in the `after_initialize` hook:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize do
    @user_info = {}
  end

  # Other stuff here
end
```

BTW, there's a huge difference between ruby and other languages: **The instance variables defined directly in the class belong to the class itself, not its instances.** Only those instance variables defined in the instance methods belong to that class's instances.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@user_info = Hash.new` in the body of `Group`'s class definition, the scoping rules of Ruby dictate that `@user_info` is an instance variable of the `Group` instance of the class `Class`. It is accessible only when `self` is `Group`, not when `self` is an instance of `Group`.

You can give yourself access to the class-level instance variable by defining a singleton method on `Group`.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  @user_info = Hash.new

  def self.user_info
    @user_info
  end

  def add_user(user_id)
    new_info = OpenStruct.new
    new_info.score1 = 0
    new_info.score2 = 0

    self.class.user_info[user_id] = new_info
    # OR: Group.user_info[user_id] = new_info
  end
end
```