# Are @@variables in a Ruby on Rails controller specific to the users session, or are all users going to see the same value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a controller in which there is a "viewless" action. That controller is used to set a variable called `@@ComputedData={}`. But the data is computed based on a csv file a user of the application uploaded. Now are users going to see their specific data or will the `@@ComputeData` be the same for all users? Could someone explain me this concept? I'm really shaky on it. Thank you in advance and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `@@` class variable for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@@ComputedData is a class variable. All users are going to see the same data, so baaaad idea.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful about using class variables in Rails.

Class variables are not shared between processes, so you will get **inconsistent results**.

For more information, look at:

1. [O'Reilly Ruby - Don't Use Class Variables!](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/01/nubygems_dont_use_class_variab_1.html)
2. [Why should we avoid using class variables @@ in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396563/why-should-we-avoid-using-class-variables-in-rails)

You can always use a class and class methods to have the same data for all users:

```
class Computation
  attr_reader :computed_data
  @computed_data = 3
end
```

So you can ask for `Computation.computed_data` (will be 3),

but `Computation.computed_data = 4` will give you a `NoMethodError`.

If you on the other side, if you want `computed_data` per user basis, you should save it on a database in an ActiveRecord Model (the typical case for Rails)...

Comment: I only want to store the computed data in the data base associated to the user. So if I choose to go with a regular ruby class, will each controller request have its own instance of that ruby class? My ruby class will be passed a file uploaded by the user. Then the class is going to parse the data and return the computed results back. Is that a safer approach?

Comment: TazMan you should start with [Rails Guides - Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and use the example for Posts have an idea of how ActiveRecord and Controllers work. Then investigate [Carrierwave gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/carrierwave) to upload files.

Comment: Please reply to the comment above. What I'm asking is not even being addressed. I'm trying to learn how controllers work! will each controller instantiation have a unique instance of that regular ruby class or not??

Comment: TazMan, my comment did answer your question. Rails is an MVC framework, where each component (Controller, Model, View) has its responsibilities, and you're trying to solve your problem like it's not MVC. You can't/shouldn't have specific user data on the Controller.

Comment: TazMan In any case, it's probably best to edit the question, even better, create a new question more specific to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse `class variables (@@)` with `global variables ($)`. 
In [this post](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm) you will see the explanation and the different between them.

Comment: I dont see why you brought up Global $ variables. I don't think that applies in my case.