# Access super variables using class object

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, factory-pattern, class-variables

Heey I am new to Ruby. I need to create a factory method, which will return me an object of a class. Using that object I should be able to access the variables of the class. I have written the following code, but I surely have miss something.

```
class Super
  @@super_temp = 1

  def Super.get_instance(world)          
    platform = world
    if @@instance == nil
      if platform==1
        @@instance = BaseA.new
      else
        @@instance = BaseB.new
      end
    end
    return @@instance
  end
end

class BaseA < Super    
  @@base_temp = 2      
end


class BaseB < Super
  @@base_temp = 3    
end


class Demo
  def Demo.call_demo
    obj = Super.get_instance(0)

    puts "---------temp is #{obj.base_temp}"      
  end
end

Demo.call_demo
```

I need to retrieve the value of base_temp in class Demo.

Comment: Why are you using class variables for this? In any case, class variables don't work like that--maybe check out some Ruby tutorials discussing the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `@@` ([Why should we avoid using class variables @@ in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396563/why-should-we-avoid-using-class-variables-in-rails)) - `@` solves your problem just as easily.

Aside from that, all that is missing in your code is a getter:

```
class Super
  @super_temp = 1

  def Super.get_instance(world)          
    platform = world
    if @instance == nil
      if platform==1
        @instance = BaseA.new
      else
        @instance = BaseB.new
      end
    end
    return @instance
  end

  def base_temp
    self.class.base_temp
  end

  def self.base_temp
    @base_temp
  end
end

class BaseA < Super    
  @base_temp = 2      
end


class BaseB < Super
  @base_temp = 3    
end


class Demo
  def Demo.call_demo
    obj = Super.get_instance(0)

    puts "---------temp is #{obj.base_temp}"      
  end
end

Demo.call_demo
# ---------temp is 3
```

The instance getter (implemented as `self.class.base_temp`) calls the class method `base_temp` of the instance's class. If we add prints of the internal products of the function, you can have some insights about its internals:

```
class Super
  def base_temp
    p self
    p self.class
    p self.class.base_temp
  end
end

BaseA.new.base_temp
# #<BaseA:0x000000027df9e0>
# BaseA
# 2

BaseB.new.base_temp
# #<BaseB:0x000000027e38b0>
# BaseB
# 3
```

Comment: Hey Uri.. I understand <def self.base_temp> is the getter method. Could you please explain how does < def base_temp
    self.class.base_temp> work. I do not completely understand the working of it.         Also since I have many variables, creating those many setter getter methods, doesn't seem like the ideal solution.

Comment: `Super.get_instance` is valid Ruby code. However, as you suggested, we should use `self.get_instance` because small change in the class name, doesn't require change in the rest of the code.

Comment: @DarekNędza - of course you are right, I've not used this syntax, so I forgot that it is legitimate. In the name of minimal code change, I've removed that observation completely.

Comment: @UriAgassi The works fine. but I was just wondering, since I have many constant variables in my code. Do I have to write those setter, getter methods for each variable(which would be a major code block), or is there a way around?

Comment: @Hades - instance and class variables are _private_ which means you can't [easily] access them outside the instance/class. You can implement getters as one liners (look for 'attr_reader')

Comment: Hades, you could write the `get_instance` class method like this: `def self.get_instance(world); @@instance ||= world==1 ? BaseA.new : BaseB.new; end`.