# Where should I save values that are commonly used in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assuming that there is a `Person` model that have a column `point` and `point_standard_score`.

To get standard score, I need to calculate standard deviation by using `point` column.
It takes some time to calculate it, so I want to save it like in database.

But I don't know where should I save the value that is used commonly from all instance of the model.

I found that we should avoid to use class variable in rails.
[Why should we avoid using class variables @@ in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396563/why-should-we-avoid-using-class-variables-in-rails)

Where and how should I save the value?

Comment: I have. I want to know where should I save the standard deviation that is calculated by all `point`s. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No. Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: usually that value should be stored in db as a field, updating on change, and reading on request, but field is not for the same table, but related with `belongs_to`.